# Adding items in <select> in Chrome works, In IE it doesnt work

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I'm making a small website and within that website there is a `<select></select>` tag. I want to automaticly fill the select when the user presses a key.

Alright? Now let go to the problem, all of the above work fine in Chrome but it doesnt work in IE. Can someone show me a way to make it work in IE?

This is what im working with:

```
// Action that gets triggered by textfield 2
            function CheckTwo() {
                if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                    AddToList();
                    document.getElementById("two").value = "";
                    GiveFocus("two");
                }                
            }

function AddToList()
            {
                var box = document.getElementById("selectbox");
                var newoption = document.createElement("option");
                newoption.text = document.getElementById("two").value;
                box.add(newoption);
            }

            // Create array of all the items of the <select></select>
            function CalculateList()
            {
                var barcodes = [];
                var options = document.getElementsByTagName("option");
                for (var i = 0; i < options.lenght; i++)
                {
                    barcodes.push(options[i].text);
                }
                var barcodestring = barcodes.join(",");
            }
```

I dont think the html is relevant for this kind of question becuase i believe that internet explorer cant handle the javascript.
But here it is in case it is the problem:

```
 <tr>


<td>Bonregel:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="bonregel" id="two" onkeyup="CheckTwo()" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Bonlijst:</td>
                    <td><select id="selectbox" multiple></select></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
```

Comment: Which version of IE?

Comment: The version i have is IE 10

Comment: whether that function is triggering?? try adding an alert inside `if`

Comment: Wich if? The one in the Check() function?

Comment: Works fine here in IE10 & IE 11: https://jsfiddle.net/re6djgfL/1/ Yet try onkeypress instead and pass the event to it CheckTwo(event) and check event.which

Comment: You know whats weird.... In JsFiddle it works for me to, But in the REAL  IE 10 it doesnt work

Comment: @CKY: Well I tested it on real IE 10 without problem.

Comment: Can it be that the button thats further in de code is messing it up? so when i press enter that the button takes that as a signal to do something?

Comment: @CKY: A lot is possible. Yet to tell for sure we would need an entire fiddle with the exact code which does not work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your function and your call a bit.

```
function CheckTwo(event){
    var tKey = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
    if (tKey == 13){
        AddToList();
        document.getElementById("two").value = "";
        GiveFocus("two");
    }                
}

<input type = 'text' name = 'bonregel' id = 'two' onkeyup = 'CheckTwo(event)' />
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Log490jk/